# Recursively Iterate through nested tags inside a div - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to navigate the div tag using Beautiful Soup to extract some data.
HTML Structure looks similar to this:

```
<div id="important-data">
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
 <p> <b> Heading Goes here </b> </p>
 <p> Paragraph goes here </p>
 <ul>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
 </ul>
 <p> Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
</div>
```

The Original HTML doc may contain more than 30 nested tags (including other tags such as span or may be even nested divs) inside the div and I need to navigate them all

Until now, I extracted the HTML and stored in a variable

```
important_data_to_be_extracted = soup.find("div", id="important-data").prettify()
## Soup here is the HTML given above
```

The Output I'm expecting is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Heading Goes here
Paragraph goes here
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Most importantly I want the EOL to be present. I tried a few techniques using .children generator or find_all() methods, but those seem too naive and clumsy.

Is there an efficient way to extract data from the structure?

Comment: easy with `target = soup.find("div", id="important-data")` and then `print(target.text)`

Comment: It doesn't produce text in a readable format

Comment: check below answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `.contents` which returns back a list of all the contents of a tag
and similarly .children

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs , Tag

html = '''
<div id="important-data">
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
 <p> <b> Heading Goes here </b> </p>
 <p> Paragraph goes here </p>
 <ul>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
 </ul>
 <p> Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
</div>'''


soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find("div", id="important-data")
for t in div.children:
        if type(t)== Tag :
                tag_text = t.text.strip()
                print(tag_text)
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua.
Heading Goes here
Paragraph goes here
Item 1
 Item 2
 Item 3
Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Comment: Works fine. But doesn't seem to preserve new line with <ul> and <li> tags! I had the same problem

Comment: @DeathJack I'm stripping out the new line , didn't know you want it . Just remove the `.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div id="important-data">
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
 <p> <b> Heading Goes here </b> </p>
 <p> Paragraph goes here </p>
 <ul>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
 </ul>
 <p> Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
</div>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

target = soup.find("div", id="important-data")

print(target.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Heading Goes here
 Paragraph goes here

 Item 1
 Item 2
 Item 3

 Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Comment: As pointed in the question, I want to each block in new line. I tried your method, it doesn't preserve new lines as how you describe it!